# Eclipse preloading wrong JDBC driver without asking

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle12c

Right now I have an oracle 12c. To connect with the database I need to use the ojdbc7.jar driver.

My own apps connect without problem with this, but I can't make SQL Explorer to work because I always get the "Not matching protocol" error. This is because is preloading the wrong JDBC driver. Now, I made a search in the Eclipse directory and I found this file:

.\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\927\0.cp\lib\ojdbc14.jar

This is the wrong driver, and SQL Explorer alway use this despite I configure the right one in the settings. I've tried deleting this but every time I launch eclipse this jar appears again.

Now, to "fix" this, I put the correct driver, and renamed it with "ojdbc14.jar". Right now is working but I just want to disable this because sometimes I need to connect to oracle 11g and I need to change all over again.

What pluggin is preloading this?

Thanks!